# Output array type column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so -

| id_sale | name |
| --- | --- |
| 20029 | Robert |
| 10029 | Christine |
| 10029 | Deborah |

How do I output this result -

| id_sale | name |
| --- | --- |
| 20029 | Robert |
| 10029 | Christine, Deborah |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an array, you would use `array_agg()`:

```
select id_sale, array_agg(name)
from t
group by id_sale;
```

If you want the value as a comma-sseparated string:

```
string_agg(name, ', ')
```